# Time complexity of a simple algorithm

Tags: c, time, complexity-theory

Hello and sorry for my bad english.

I'm still trying to estimate a complexity of a following algorithm.

There is:

```
int f = 1, n, x, licznik = 0;
printf("Variable of n: ");
scanf("%d", &n);
printf("Variable of x: ");
scanf("%d", &x);

while(n > 0) {
        if(n%2 == 0) {
                x = x*x;
                n = n/2;
                licznik++;
        }
        else {
                f = f*x;
                n = n-1;
                licznik++;
        }
}
```

My observation:

When n = / then / licznik =

n = 0
l = 0

n = 10
l = 5

n = 100
l = 9

n = 1000
l = 15

n = 10000
l = 18

n = 1 000 000
l = 26

So it's still growing but very slowly. So it's looks like a "log n" function.
It's a good answer that time complexity for this algorithm is O(log n)? What about best option and the worst? Thanks for your help.

PS: "licznik" is a number of multiplications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, lets take a wider look..

in your algorithm, once the value is `halved` and next time its `decremented` by 1.. since the decrement is almost negligible to the division (for very large values).. we can consider that the value (approximately) is just being divided once in 2 iterations.. Then the time complexity becomes `O(2logn)..  which is really O(logn)..

Comment: Helo, thank you.
So my answer was good? What about the worst option? Because the question is - "Which type "n" should be to get the most of "licznik" and how type to get lest?

Comment: @Lawliet: yes, your answer was good.. and there is no worst or best option in your code.. it will be the same everytime.. best or worst option come into picture when there is a possibilty of some execution gettin skipped due to some condition..

Answer (score 2):

If `n` is an odd number you will always decrement it by one, making it even and guaranteeing  that it will get divided into half in the next iteration.

In the worst case you get 2*log n which is O(log n) complexity.

Comment: Hello, thanks you.
Can you tell a bit more about how did you calculate it?

Comment: @Lawliet Take a large number and divide it until you hit 1. Then compare the number of divisions performed to a binary log of the original number. The same happens in your code when you divide n.

Comment: The worst case scenario is when n is of the form (2^n - 1) which you can see by construction. In that case each "step" is going to require a subtraction to make it even and a division to make it odd again. That gives you two times through the loop for each division. That is, 2 * lg n.